# XSLT Transformations for specific occurence of value

Tags: xml, xslt

During the integration of an API, I am trying to select the first occurrence where the value of the  Tag matches a specific string, and discounts all of the rest.

Below is a snippet of the code I have.

```
<Body>
<Envelope>
<GetCollectionResponse>
<GetCollectionResult>
    <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <Service>Service One</Service>
            <Day>Tuesday</Day>
            <Date>18/07/2017</Date>
        </Collection>
        <Collection>
            <Service>Service Two</Service>
            <Day>Wednesday</Day>
            <Date>19/07/2017</Date>
        </Collection>
        <Collection>
            <Service>Service One</Service>
            <Day>Thursday</Day>
            <Date>20/07/2017</Date>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</GetCollectionResult>
</GetCollectionResponse>
</Envelope>
</Body>
```

Ideally, I would like it to fetch the first occurence whereby the Service matches '*Service One*' - retrieving the information as shown below, rather than the second occurence.

```
<Service>Service One</Service
<Day>Tuesday</Day>
<Date>18/07/2017</Date>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `value-of` element of XSLT. It get the first element matching the XPath. See description and example: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_value_of.asp

Your XPath could be something like following for getting the value for the Day:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/Body/Envelope/GetCollectionResponse/GetCollectionResult/Collections/Collection[Service='Service One']/Day"/>
```

and the equivalent for your Date

Comment: Would you be suggesting something like I've done here?

https://justpaste.it/1959o

Comment: if you correct the first value-of, yes. It will print you both selected values. The "try It yourself" editor of w3School is quite adapted for you to test.

Comment: Didn't realise the typo there, I have changed the values of each of the fields just for this example. Using the code I linked to above has yielded no results from my dataset. 

I'm pretty new to XSLT so its not a strong point of mine

Comment: "*`value-of` element of XSLT. It get the first element matching the XPath.*" That's true in XSLT 1.0, not in later versions. This question does not state the version - and even in XSLT 1.0 it's better to select the occurrence expressly, both for clarity of code and for future compatibility.

Comment: Just made some corrections to my XSLT - seems to be working perfectly now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally, I would like it to fetch the first occurence whereby the
>   Service matches 'Service One'

Since you want multiple nodes from this `Service`, it might be convenient to place it in a variable first, then use it to get the individual elements:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Body">
    <!--  "the first occurence whereby the Service matches 'Service One'" is: -->
    <xsl:variable name="my-service" select="Envelope/GetCollectionResponse/GetCollectionResult/Collections/Collection[Service='Service One'][1]"/>
    <!--  output -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="$my-service/Service"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$my-service/Day"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$my-service/Date"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the output is not well-formed XML (does not have a single root element).

---

Of course, in the given example you could shorten this to:

```
<xsl:template match="/Body">
    <xsl:copy-of select="Envelope/GetCollectionResponse/GetCollectionResult/Collections/Collection[Service='Service One'][1]/*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to get all child elements of the selected `Service`.